# Get every second post in WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I need to seperate loops in two colums and want to skip every second loop in each loop. At the end I need a view like this:

**Loop 1**

- Post **1**
- Post **3**
- Post **5**

**Loop 2**

- Post **2**
- Post **4**
- Post **6**

Is that possible?

My current loop:

```
<?php $args = array (
                'nopaging'               => true,
                'posts_per_page'         => '999',
                'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
            );

            $query_row_1 = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $query_row_1->have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php while ( $query_row_1->have_posts() ) : $query_row_1->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: please be more specific what you want and what you have already tried. This is very little information and certainly not enough to help you

Comment: I have a normal WordPress loop which returns every post by date. But want I need is a loop, which returns only every second post begining with the latest post. And a second loop which returns every second post beginning at the second latest post. Like I showed in my question. Two loops witch skip of every second post

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: code pasted in question above

Comment: I do not really understand your code but I would say make a variable `$counter = 0;` and increase it in every run ( `$counter++;` ). Then make a if stamement like this: `if($counter % 2) { continue; }` This will skip every second run of the while loop

Comment: If this works I can puit it in the answer :)

Comment: it works, thank you!

Comment: That is great :)
I posted an answer with explanation and the code. I would highly appreciate it if you upvate and accept this since it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already commented:

You can declare a counter variable like this:

```
$counter = 0;
```

And in the while loop insert these four lines at the beginning:

```
$counter++;
if($counter % 2)
{
    continue;
}
```

This increases the counter with one and checks whether the counter is even or not. Since the outcome is only 0 or 1 it can be directly used in the if confition because this represents true or false.
If it if odd the while loops jumps to the next run and if it is even the rest of the loop continues. If you want to switch even and off make the if statement like this `if(!($counter % 2))`